Unable to create pipeline because previous job is not in any previous stage
I am using the gitlab pipeline for unit testing, building, pushing, and deploying the below pipeline script.
image: node:18.13.0

default:
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''
  API_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/apps/api'
  WEB_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/apps/web'
  FF_USE_FASTZIP: 'true'
  # These can be specified per job or per pipeline
  ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: 'fast'
  CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: 'fast'

stages:
  - pre-check
  - quality
  - build
  - push
  - deploy

validate_branch_name:
  stage: pre-check
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME | grep -Eq '^feature\/|^bugfix\/|^release\/' || (echo "Invalid branch name"; exit 1)
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: always

validate_commit_message:
  stage: pre-check
  script:
    - |
      if ! git log -1 --pretty=%B | grep -Eq '^(feat|fix|chore|docs|style|refactor|test|perf): .+'; then
        echo "Invalid commit message format"
        exit 1
      fi
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: always

unit_test:
  image: node:18.13.0
  stage: test
  needs:
    - validate_branch_name
    - validate_commit_message
  script:
    - npm run test:web
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/coverage/
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/coverage/**/**/cobertura-coverage.xml
  allow-failure: true
  only:
    - develop
  retry:
    max: 1
    when: always

# check the code quality using sonar-scanner
sonarqube_check:
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  stage: push
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: '${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar'
    GIT_DEPTH: '0'
  cache:
    key: '${CI_JOB_NAME}'
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  before_script:
    - export VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
  script:
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectVersion=$VERSION
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - develop
  needs:
    - job: unit_test
      artifacts: true

# install node modules
.distributed:
  interruptible: true
  before_script:
    - npm install --location=global npm-cli-login
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - .npm/
      - node_modules
    policy: pull-push
  retry:
    max: 2
    when: always

# push the images to the gitlab container registry for the serverfull deployment
.push_serverfull:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  stage: push
  cache: {}
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  script:
    - docker login $REGISTRY -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD

  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
    expire_in: 60 min

# dev environment
build_dev:
  image: node:18.13.0
  stage: build
  extends: .distributed
  script:
    - export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
    - npx semantic-release
    - npx nx affected --target=build --all --parallel=3 --configuration=dev
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/
    expire_in: 60 min
  only:
    - develop
  environment:
    name: dev

push_dev:
  extends: .push_serverfull
  only:
    - develop
  environment:
    name: dev
  needs:
    - job: build_dev
      artifacts: true

When click on update we can't run this pipeline because error coming with below message. How can solve this?
**Unable to create pipeline**
'unit_test' job needs '**validate_branch_name**' job, but '**validate_branch_name**' is not in any previous stage
'unit_test' job needs '**validate_commit_message**' job, but '**validate_commit_message**' is not in any previous stage

Without adding the above mentioned "validate_commit_message" and "validate_branch_name" pipeline is running perfectly only this error message comes with adding these jobs to pipeline.
